# Transferred from old iPhone to new iPhone and shared items in Messages app didn’t sync

Tags: iphone, icloud, messages, data-transfer

I’m transferring from an old iPhone SE 2nd Generation (iOS 16.3.1), to a new iPhone 14+ (iOS 16.4) using the out-of-the-box-keep-the-phones-near-each-other wireless transfer method. The transfer process seems to have completed successfully, or at least mostly successfully. All my apps and preferences have transferred over, as well as all my text messages from the Messages app.

However, when I click on a conversation with any person and click on their name to open up the conversation info panel, where I usually see sections for all of the things we’ve shared through Messages (i.e. Photos, Links, Documents, and Collaboration), none of those things have transferred over except for a couple of random images. Some conversations have a “13 images in iCloud / Download“ button, but not all. For example, the ongoing conversation with my partner, with whom I have shared many gigabytes of photos, links, etc., does not have that option available and currently shows only 8 random images as having ever been shared between us. When I scroll back through the history of the same conversation, I can still see the photos and videos and links I have sent or received, but they don’t show up on the info panel as having been shared.

I currently have my Messages app set to be backed up as part of iCloud, which lists about 24 gigs of storage space as being used for Messages alone. And before I initiated the phone transfer, I made sure to back up my old phone to iCloud and locally to my MacBook.

Why haven’t my shared items transferred over within the Messages app? And what can I do to get them?

---

Edit to add additional info:

- My MacBook, which is set to sync the Messages app, still has all the shared content that my old phone has
- Both phones have the same capacity (128 GB) but old phone says 43.64 GB available, new phone says 49.5 GB. Interestingly, when I go into General > iPhone Storage, the old phone says Messages is using 2.24 GB, while the new phone is currently using 21.33 GB for Messages. Drilling down into more detail the new phone says that I’m using 13.95 GB on video stored in Messages, but clicking in to list those videos only shows me two (which I have explicitly revisited on this phone).

Comment: When you say you transferred from phone to phone - there are several manners to do that. Do you recall precisely what method you chose? You can always erase the new phone and start over if the old is still set up correctly.

Comment: I used the out-of-the-box-keep-the-phones-near-each-other wireless transfer method, with all the default settings (as far as I can remember). The other phone is still set up, but I’m hoping to find a solution before a resort to that

Comment: I've rarely seen messages catch up if they don't transfer direct, but you might still be in luck. The wired direct transfer is much more reliable in my experience - https://www.imore.com/how-use-iphone-iphone-setup One reason to wait would be if you went into photos and saw images from messages that are not yet imported and also are not yet downloaded into the messages app...

Comment: How much free space does the old phone think it has and is the new phone the same storage or larger than the old?

Comment: Same capacity (128 GB). Old phone says 43.64 GB available, new phone says 49.5 GB. Interestingly, when I go into General > iPhone storage, the old phone says Messages is using 2.24 GB, while the new phone is currently using 21.33 GB for Messages. Drilling down into more detail the new phone says that I’m using 13.95 GB on video stored in Messages, but clicking in to list those videos only shows me two (which I have explicitly revisited on this phone).

Comment: Definitely edit that last set of details into the body of the post. No red flags other than "cloud" sync can be odd. As long as you can power down the old phone or keep it close to ready - there's no need to rush an erase - wait a week shouldn't harm things too much IMO